# How do I add spaces in front of integer array parameters?

Tags: c

I have an array like this

`int numbers[]={5,6,5,8,9,1,-6516,8,811,981,981};`

and I need to print them to screen with spaces in front of them so the total number of characters printed will be 4. si the number 5 will be printed as 3 spaces and 5    `5` the number 811 will be  `811` and so on.

Comment: `printf("%4d", number);`

Comment: Just about any decent book, tutorial or class should have mentioned the formatting specifiers for `printf`, including how to set *field width* and *justification*.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the code which outputs the values but fails to format them as desired. Depending on your approach the answer is different, mostly in the detail of the documentation of which of the functions you used contains the information you missed. Assuming that you did read them....

Comment: Let's not downvote a question for being a newbie question. Let's point him to good resources instead.

Answer (score 2):

As was previously mentioned in comments, this is something you can do with printf. I'm reluctant to write the code because a) it looks like homework and b) you'll have this nailed once you've read up on printf. (You'll need to put that printf in a for-loop to go thru the array, for sure, so read up on for as well if you need to.)

Some good resources for printf are whatever textbook you're using, plus
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm
https://www.dummies.com/programming/c/how-to-format-with-printf-in-c-programming/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ (a reference, not a tutorial)

Comment: I teeter between upvoting this and flagging it as link-only NAA. But concerning how much I like the quality of the question....